# VerifyError: Error #1014: Не удалось найти класс as3isolib.display.scene::IsoScene

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Собственно вот такая ситуация:
[image]

При запуске дебага компилятор говорит:

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Не удалось найти класс
>   as3isolib.display.scene::IsoScene.

Почему Flash Builder не может найти класс, который импортирован и находиться в правильной директории? Как это можно исправить?

**UPD:** Я не понимаю как, но после 45 минутного ожидания и следующего запуска ошибка исчезла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать Clean проекту.

Там ничего лишнего в библиотеках нет?

Код проекта можно посмотреть?

Тестовый проект не запускали? Например где просто IsoScene с IsoBox?

Comment: Проблема решилась простым ожиданием, думаю Flash Builder протер глазки и ему удалось найти класс.

Comment: С полгода перешел на FlashDevelop, там таких чудесных сюрпризов побольше. FlashBuilder вообще тихоня, когда к нему привыкаешь. :)